# Using AWK: how to define printing fields to search for rows containing dates ranging between today and 5 days ago?

Tags: awk, date, filter

I'm trying to summarise this list to contain only 5 days worth of data, from today to 5 days ago. I tried using `awk` but to no avail. There is no need to stick to awk too. This is the output:

This is my `awk` code to search for `today's` date in a row:

```
awk -F " " -v todate="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" 'todate' output.txt
```

This is my while loop code:

```
while read line
    do
    if (("$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" in $line))
        then
            echo $line
done < output.txt
```

This is the `output.txt` file:

```
2018-05-09 14:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-10 03:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-10 16:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-11 05:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-11 18:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-12 07:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-12 20:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-13 09:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-13 22:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-14 11:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-15 00:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-15 08:00:00 UTC+0800;swlt;;BKP_USGSN03_OLP_MK8;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-15 08:00:00 UTC+0800;sau;;2025,licensed_sau_normal;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-15 08:00:00 UTC+0800;sau_lte;;1025,licensed_sau_lte_normal;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-15 08:00:00 UTC+0800;pdp;;2001,licensed_pdp_normal;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-15 13:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-16 02:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-16 15:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-17 04:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-17 17:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-18 06:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-18 19:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-19 08:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-19 21:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-20 10:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-20 23:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-21 12:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-22 01:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-22 14:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-23 03:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
```

Comment: Given the clarifying comments on the answers so far, I think it’d be helpful to edit in your “date -d” restriction.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible, because the list is non-static, it updates everyday in a crontab schedule. I have checked the man page for the date command in my system and found no other options that could call up the dates of the past 5 days.

Answer (score 1):

In the following script, the function `mktime` creates a unix timestamp based on the 1st and 2nd field of the file that can be compared with the reference date from `date` given in argument to `awk`:

```
awk -v startdate=$(date -d '5 days ago' +%s) '{d=$1 OFS $2; gsub("[-:]", " ", d); t=mktime(d)} t>startdate' file
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU **`awk`** approach:

```
awk -F'[:-]' -v from_date=$(date -d'-4 days' +%s) \
'mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)) >= from_date' file.txt
```

Sample output:

```
2018-05-18 06:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-18 19:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-19 08:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-19 21:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-20 10:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-20 23:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-21 12:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-22 01:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-22 14:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-23 03:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for helping. Im a first time user, so pardon me if i type unclear in this forum. 
I have a problem with the argument that you're passing into your "date" command. The system does not recognise -d. when i apply this command:
    
    $ date -d'-4 days' +%s    

The result is: 

    date: illegal option -- d
    date: illegal option -- -
    date: illegal option -- 4
    date: illegal option --
    date: illegal option -- d
    date: invalid argument -- ys
    usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]

Answer (score 0):

Using **AWK:**

OPTION 1:

```
DATE=`date --date='5 days ago' +"%Y-%m-%d"`;awk '/'$DATE'/,EOF { print $0 }' file.txt
```

OPTION 2:

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "5 day ago"`;awk '/'$DATE'/,EOF { print $0 }' file.txt
```

OPTION 3:

```
awk '/2018-05-18/,EOF { print $0 }' file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
2018-05-18 06:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-18 19:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-19 08:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-19 21:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-20 10:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-20 23:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-21 12:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-22 01:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-22 14:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
2018-05-23 03:40:22 UTC+0800;sau;;less_than_100,heartbeat;CXS101289_R73B13(001-00-12)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping! I'm a first time user and i amazed at the help. However, i havent been able to use the --date argument in my date command. It says Illegal option.usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]

Comment: Updated my answer , Try option 2

Comment: something's wrong. -d isn't working either. I'm getting DATE=2018-05-23: Command not found. DATE: Undefined variable. I suspect the date command in my system does not take in -d argument. This might help, the usage is specified as: "usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]"

Comment: Which distro of Linux are you using?

Comment: I think it means that only -u and -a arguments are legal, just a wild guess.

Comment: Let me know which OS are you using and check `man` page or `--help`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion to check man page. I checked and there are indeed only two options in my system, -a and -u. The capabilities of this system is limited.

Comment: then you have to give static value for `date` in script or run-time as an argument as my option 3

Comment: hmm, im sorry, i cannot do a static date. The output.txt is a output of a crontab schedule and will be automatically updated every day at a specified time. It is a running process. Thank you for the help, but I realised there is no way i can specify what are the dates of the last five days without the --date option or -d option, so there might be no way i can do this summary. Unless i can change the options of date command somehow